Why doesn't subset function work for a dataframe from a website?
I import a dataframe with library rvest and I want to sort it with subset function, import is alright, cause I can print a dataframe. But when I want to sort data from it, I see error object not found. What should I do?
library(rvest)
html_content <- read_html(url("https://ki.ujep.cz/cs/historie/"))
table <- html_table(html_content, header = TRUE)
print(subset(table, subset = `Dosud na UJEP?` == "ANO"))

I have tested function subset for iris dataframe and it works perfectly, so I don't know what I have to do else

Two alternatives
library(rvest)

# table = 
"https://ki.ujep.cz/cs/historie/" |>
  read_html() |>
  html_element(xpath = "/html/body/div/main/article/div/div/figure/table") |>
  html_table(header = TRUE) |>
  subset(`Dosud na UJEP?` == "ANO")

# table = 
"https://ki.ujep.cz/cs/historie/" |>
  read_html() |>
  html_table(header = TRUE) |>
  purrr::pluck(2L) |>
  subset(`Dosud na UJEP?` == "ANO")


As written, table is returning a list of tibbles. The one you want is the second item.
```{r}
str(table)

```

List of 2
 $ : tibble [5 × 7] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ Po: int [1:5] NA 6 13 20 27
  ..$ Út: int [1:5] NA 7 14 21 28
  ..$ St: int [1:5] 1 8 15 22 29
  ..$ Čt: int [1:5] 2 9 16 23 30
  ..$ Pá: int [1:5] 3 10 17 24 31
  ..$ So: int [1:5] 4 11 18 25 NA
  ..$ Ne: int [1:5] 5 12 19 26 NA
 $ : tibble [9 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ Jméno         : chr [1:9] "Doc. RNDr. Jan Kopka, CSc." "Ing. Zdeněk Fikar" "Ing. Mgr. Jiří Barilla" "Doc. Ing. Prokop Toman, CSc." ...
  ..$ Od            : int [1:9] 1987 1991 1993 1996 2001 2006 2009 2011 2014
  ..$ Do            : chr [1:9] "1991" "1993" "1996" "2001" ...
  ..$ Dosud na UJEP?: chr [1:9] "NE" "NE" "ANO" "NE" ...

It can be accessed with [[]]
```{r}
table[[2]]
```


So slightly changing your last line to the following produces what appears to be the desired result.
```{r}
print(subset(table[[2]], subset = `Dosud na UJEP?` == "ANO"))
```



I don't undeerstand how you can figure out it's exactly 2. Iris dataframe doesn't request anything after the name.

Since [[2]] is returned by your print-line as index of the tibble containing the column Dosud na UJEP?  you try to subset on.

Iris is a single df. I determined which dataframe you wanted by using str() to get the objects structure. From there, I looked at the column names and saw the column you were looking for in the second dataset. From there use the [[]] indexer to retrieve the correct item in the list.

You should select what table want to select from. Just add table[[2]]
> print(subset(table[[2]], subset = `Dosud na UJEP?` == "ANO"))
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  Jméno                                Od Do    `Dosud na UJEP?`
  <chr>                             <int> <chr> <chr>           
1 Ing. Mgr. Jiří Barilla             1993 1996  ANO             
2 Ing. Mgr. Jiří Barilla, CSc.       2001 2006  ANO             
3 Prof. RNDr. Ivo Nezbeda, DrSc.     2006 2008  ANO             
4 Doc. RNDr. Viktor Mashkov, DrSc.   2009 2011  ANO             
5 prof. RNDr. Stanislav Novák, CSc.  2011 2014  ANO             
6 RNDr. Jiří Škvor, Ph.D.            2014 Dosud ANO          


thank you very much, it really works. But I don't understand what does it mean "select what table want to select from".

And why should we add exactly 2, not 1 for example? 2 even isn't an index of the column, I want to select from

Because html_table() returns a list of two tibbles in your case, see the output of your print-line. [[2]] is the second element of your list table

@Friede finally got it! We have two dataframes on this page. I didn't think calendar recognizes as a dataframe too. So can we choose dataframe we want to import to avoid using index of the dataframe? For example to add another parameter to read_html function with this name?

Have you tried table <- html_table(html_content, header = TRUE)[[2]]? Another way would be to inspect the web page with a browser's developer console and choose an identifier which can be passed to a rvest-function as html-tag or XPath
